# Installbuilder - sign uninstaller

Tags: windows-installer

I have an issue where the file produced by the installbuilder gets signed but not its corresponding uninstaller. Anyone who might have an idea on how to solve this?

https://releases.installbuilder.com/installbuilder/docs/installbuilder-userguide/_code_signing.html

```html
    <postBuildActionList>
        <runProgram>
            <program>smctl</program>
            <programArguments>sign ... with params</programArguments>
            <ruleList>
                <platformTest>
                    <type>windows</type>
                </platformTest>
            </ruleList>
        </runProgram>
    </postBuildActionList>
```